# Tracking in Google Analytics via Tag Manager

Tags: css, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We are facing the following tracking problem in GTM:
Here, The scenario is that, there are two sections in our webpage. Both the sections have multiple divisions and other elements. The class name of division in first section is, let's say 'a' and the classname of division in second section is, let's say 'b', each div is having a button in it.  We are tracking number of clicks on each button in Google Analytics by sending an event to GA. The triggering condition for the tag is based on the CSS classes of the division. The problem here is that, when we are clicking on the button in first division the tag of the second button is also getting triggered. While clicking on the second button, only the tag associated with the second division is getting triggered. Can anyone please tell me What could be the reasons, for both the tags are getting triggered, even if the triggering conditions, i.e., the classsname of the Divisions are completely different?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if we can see how you've set up your triggers and variables

Comment: The first trigger has condition Click Element matches css selector .a for the tag for first division.
and the second trigger condition Click Element matches css selector .b for the tag for second division.

Answer (score 0):

Check the trigger on the tag ones its fired with the Dubugger.

[image]

This way you can know which part of the condition is failing and fix it.

(If you like send me the page and which ones are the buttons and i ll tell u how to do it)